# Can't retrieve a valid WinSAT assessment. javascript console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, extjs, extjs4, aptana3

i frequently get this error when running my web app on google chrome

```
[2536:2008:0502/143602:ERROR:gpu_info_collector_win.cc(96)] Can't retrieve a valid WinSAT assessment.
```

its ok in firefox and IE..

i've already search for solutions but with no luck.

i am using Aptana Studio + Sencha

how to get rid of this?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=209

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error when I was providing the path to `chrome.exe` as the system property - it went away when I was using `chromedriver.exe` as downloaded from here: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

Answer (score 0):

This means that winsat validation failed.
Winsat is a tool that checks out windows. If it fails, normally this indicates that something is wrong with your system (probably a driver).

In the above case, I would go with the display adapter driver, so try to update it via the Windows Update.

To run winsat yourself, you can run 'winsat formal' from the command line. Then you can look for suspicious output (if you have 0 F/S performance in the direct3d, then this is not fine :-))

Based on the problematic output, you can see what is wrong in the system (in the above example, the display adapter was found as a standard VGA, and a simple  update, fixed the error made chrome/selenium).

HTH